# Apache mod_xsendfile running on Windows / WAMP - not working as it should

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, php, wamp

Okay - I have a WAMP-setup with mod_xsendfile installed - it is loaded in the `modules`-folder in the Apache-folder under WAMP, and the appropriate lines has been added to `httpd.conf`, and the module shows up in the list when I check the available modules via the WAMP-icon.

However, I can't for the life of me get it to actually work. I use it in a webpage I'm developing to send thumbnails / images / files to a gallery, and this works just fine on a MAMP-server where I did the first development. I'm using PHP for the backend, and am posting the relevant code here - if you need anything else, I would be happy to provide it.

First: `httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule xsendfile_module modules/mod_xsendfile.so
<IfModule mod_xsendfile.so>
  <Files *.php>
    XSendFile On
    SetEnv MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED 1
  </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Not entirely sure about that  bit, but I've also tried this, without success:

```
# Enable mod_xsendfile
#permitted values on/off
XSendFile on
# XSendFilePath allow you to add additional paths to some
# kind of white list. All files within these paths are
#allowed to get served through mod_xsendfile
XSendFilePath "c:\wamp\www\uploadr\users\"
```

Here's the PHP-file which is returning files via X-Sendfile:

```
<?php
require_once('conf/config.php');
if (!session_id()) { session_start(); };

$username = (($isloggedin && isset($_GET['user'])) ? $_GET['user'].'/' : ((!$isloggedin) ? 'public/' : $username));
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && $username != 'public/') {
    $potential_public_file = explode('__',explode('=',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])[1])[0];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($user_array); $i++) {
        $exploded_user_array = explode('//',$user_array[$i]);
        if (($potential_public_file == trim($exploded_user_array[0]))) {
            $username = 'public/';
        }
    }
}
    if ($debug == true) {
        logThis('showfile_processing','Username is set to '.$username.''."\r\n",FILE_APPEND);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['imgfile'])) {
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        if (isset($_GET['thumbs'])) {
            header('X-Sendfile: '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$userpath.$username.'pictures/thumbs/'.$_GET['imgfile']);
        } else {
            header('X-Sendfile: '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$userpath.$username.'pictures/'.$_GET['imgfile'].'');
        }
    } elseif (isset($_GET['docfile'])) {
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_GET['docfile'].'');
        header('X-Sendfile: '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$userpath.$username.'documents/'.$_GET['docfile'].'');
    } elseif (isset($_GET['vidfile'])) {
        if (isset($_GET['thumbs'])) {
            if ($debug == true) {
                logThis('showfile_processing','Thumbs loaded '.$_GET['vidfile']."\r\n",FILE_APPEND);    
            }
            header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
            header('X-Sendfile: '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$userpath.$username.'video/thumbs/'.$_GET['vidfile']);
        } else {
            if ($debug == true) {
                logThis('showfile_processing','Video returned '.$_GET['vidfile']."\r\n",FILE_APPEND);
            }
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_GET['vidfile'].'');
            header('X-Sendfile: '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$userpath.$username.'video/'.$_GET['vidfile'].'');
        }
    }
    exit;
?>
```

And I'm calling those files from the gallery.php-file, something like this: `showfile.php?imgfile=<name_of_file>` - it basically reads through a directory, and pulls the files via X-Sendfile to mask the placement of the files on the server from the user.

(This question was first asked on Server Fault, but they suggested I move it here)

**UPDATE**
I tried going directly to the showfile.php, and loading an image there, and I get a new error:
`The image “http://uploadr.loc/showfile?imgfile=05_196132738.jpg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.` as an `alt`-text. Regardless of which image I'm trying to load, it returns this error. Tested the exact same pictures on my MAMP-setup, they work just fine. So I'm wondering if there is a something specific either with the Windows setup, or the path to the file that creates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

And, wow, did it take me a long time to find this out, but I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133819/x-sendfile-on-apache2-php-serving-0b-file-no-errors-though

I had to set the `XSendFilePath` to `C:/` - and it magically works. That's Windows for you...